# how display x numbers of widget in flutter

Tags: flutter

EDIT :

Here is my result now :

[image]
As you can see i have make a lot of work and now it is good Advanced. Now i have the 5 Numbers selected (5-34-37-42-49) in red just at top of the 2 green buttons. For the moment the function getWidget return the 5 Numbers in red using gridview again but not sure it is what i need to use. Can you help me for resolve the problem with the size of the 5 circles, i need it centered and not use scroll.

Here is my complete code Under :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_app/menu_member.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/globals.dart' as globals;

class Lotto extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LottoState createState() => new _LottoState();
}

class _LottoState extends State<Lotto> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  var i=1;
  var nb_num=49;
  var no_select=[];
  var no_a_select=5;

  List<Color> colorList = List<Color>.generate(49, (int index) => Colors.lightBlue);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text('GRILLE DE LOTTO'),
          ),
            body:
            Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width:400,
                    height:30,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                      child : new Text("Selectionnez 5 numéros",textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width:400,
                    height:300,
                child: new GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 9,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                children: new List<Widget>.generate(49, (index) {
                  return new GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        if (colorList[index] == Colors.lightBlue) {
                          if (no_select.length<no_a_select) {
                            colorList[index] = Colors.redAccent;
                            no_select.add(index+1);
                          }
                          else {
                            showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (BuildContext context){
                                  return AlertDialog(
                                    title: Text("INFORMATION"),
                                    content: Text("Vous ne pouvez pas sélectionner plus de 5 numéros !!!"),
                                  );
                                }
                            );
                          }
                          print(no_select);
                        }
                        else {
                          colorList[index] = Colors.lightBlue;
                          no_select.remove(index+1);
                          print(no_select);
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      child: ClipOval(
                        child: Container(
                          color: colorList[index],
                          height: 20.0,
                          width: 20.0,
                          child: Center(
                            child: new Text((index+1).toString(),
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                ),
              ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width:400,
                    height:30,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                      child : new Text("Vos Numéros",textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width:400,
                    height:80,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                  child:
                    getWidget()
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width:300,
                    height:45,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                    child:
                  RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(9, 9, 9, 9),
                    child: Text('TIRAGE ALEATOIRE'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Select_numbers();
                    },
                  ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width:300,
                    height:45,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                    child:
                  RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(9, 9, 9, 9),
                    child: Text('VALIDER VOTRE GRILLE'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Valide_grille();
                    },
                  ),
                  ),
                  ]
              )
                          ),
                        ),
                    );
  }

  getWidget() {
    if (no_select.length==0) {
      return Text("Pas de numéros");
    }
    else {
      return GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 5,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          children: new List<Widget>.generate(no_select.length, (index) {
            return  ClipOval(
            child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
    height: 20.0,
    width: 20.0,
    child: Center(
    child: new Text((no_select[index].toString()),
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
    textAlign: TextAlign.center),
    ),
    ),
    );
          }
    )
      );
    }
  }

  Select_numbers() {
    setState(() {
      var j = 1;
      var num_sel;
      var pos_sel;
      no_select=[];
      colorList=[];
      colorList=List<Color>.generate(49, (int index) => Colors.lightBlue);
      var rng = new Random();
      List tab=[];
      tab = List.generate(49, (int index) => index + 1);
      print (tab);
      while (j <= no_a_select) {
        pos_sel = rng.nextInt(tab.length-1);
        num_sel=tab[pos_sel];
        no_select.add(num_sel);
        colorList[num_sel-1] = Colors.redAccent;
        tab.remove(num_sel);
        print(tab);
        j++;
      }
      print(no_select);
    });
  }

  Future Valide_grille() async{
    // For CircularProgressIndicator.
    bool visible = false ;
    // Showing CircularProgressIndicator.
    setState(() {
      visible = true ;
    });

    // SERVER LOGIN API URL
    var url = 'https://www.easytrafic.fr/game_app/valide_lotto.php';

    // Store all data with Param Name.
    var data = {'id_membre':globals.id_membre, 'result':no_select};

    print (data);

    var grille_encode=jsonEncode(data);

    print(grille_encode);

    // Starting Web API Call.
    var response = await http.post(url, body: grille_encode,headers: {'content-type': 'application/json','accept': 'application/json','authorization': globals.token});

    print(response.body);

    // Getting Server response into variable.
    var message = json.decode(response.body);

    // If the Response Message is Matched.
    if(message == 'OK')
    {
      print('VALIDATION DE LA GRILLE OK');
      // Hiding the CircularProgressIndicator.
      setState(() {
        visible = false;
      });

    }else{
      // Hiding the CircularProgressIndicator.
      setState(() {
        visible = false;
      });

      // Showing Alert Dialog with Response JSON Message.
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: new Text(message),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: new Text("OK"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need a `Flutter simple Alert Dialog` instead of `print` command. So change your code :

> ```
>  print(
>    "Vous ne pouvez pas sélectionner plus de 5 numéros !!!");
> ```

to:

```
showDialog(
     context: context,
     builder: (BuildContext context){
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Alert Dialog"),
          content: Text("Vous ne pouvez pas sélectionner plus de 5 numéros !!!"),
          );
        }
     );
```

Because `print` command sends its output to `console`.
I suggest you read this: https://dev.to/mightytechno/flutter-alert-dialog-to-custom-dialog-1ok4

```
Edit:
```

In order to have 49 circles between the buttons, you need move these lines of your code:

```
          Expanded(
            flex:2,
            child:
            RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.green,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(9, 9, 9, 9),
              child: Center(child: Text('TIRAGE ALEATOIRE')),
              onPressed: () {
                Select_numbers();
              },
            ),
          ),
```

after these lines:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('GRILLE DE LOTTO'),
        ),
        body:
        Center(
            child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
```

Also in order to make a RaisedButton's corners rounded, you can add this code:

```
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),),
```

after `RaisedButton(`

Comment: Thanks :)  I have corrected it and updated the original post with the new code. Do you know how i can display correctly the buttons at the Bottom as i say in my original post ?

Comment: i have updated the post with the complete and new code. I need to resolve the 5 Numbers selected (in red) in the zone bordered in light blue with the 5 Numbers in it just at the top of the 2 buttons. Numbers are good but design is poor, circles are too big and i am not sure i need use gridview again. The 5 circles in red in the blue light rectangular zone are generate by the function getWidget(). Thanks for your help

Comment: I think it is a good idea that you read this page: [Flutter — Effectively scale UI according to different screen sizes](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-effectively-scale-ui-according-to-different-screen-sizes-2cb7c115ea0a)

Comment: oh yes :) I understand  Set fixed width is a problem so we can set a percentage of screen which is better. Have you an idea of how i can resize the red circles because they are too big and when i change the width/height the problems is the same. I think it is gridview the problem because when you say you want 5 circles by line, it change size of circle, it increase the size automatically or reduce the size it dépends on the number of elements you want to display by lines

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use List to keep color of each number 
code snippet

```
List<Color> colorList = List<Color>.generate(49, (int index) => Colors.lightBlue);
...
setState(() {
                    if (colorList[index] == Colors.lightBlue) {
                      if (no_select.length < no_a_select) {
                        colorList[index] = Colors.redAccent;
...
 child: Container(
                      color: colorList[index],
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Lotto extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LottoState createState() => new _LottoState();
}

class _LottoState extends State<Lotto> {
  Color color;
  void message() {
    print('Clicked');
  }

  List<Color> colorList = List<Color>.generate(49, (int index) => Colors.lightBlue);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    color = Colors.lightBlue;
    print(colorList[0].toString());
  }

  var i = 1;
  var nb_num = 49;
  var no_select = [];
  var no_a_select = 5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: new GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 7,
                  children: new List<Widget>.generate(49, (index) {
                    return new GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (colorList[index] == Colors.lightBlue) {
                            if (no_select.length < no_a_select) {
                              colorList[index] = Colors.redAccent;
                              no_select.add(index + 1);
                            } else {
                              print(
                                  "Vous ne pouvez pas sélectionner plus de 5 numéros !!!");
                            }
                            print(no_select);
                          } else {
                            colorList[index] = Colors.lightBlue;
                            no_select.remove(index + 1);
                            print(no_select);
                          }
                        });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        child: ClipOval(
                          child: Container(
                            color: colorList[index],
                            height: 20.0,
                            width: 20.0,
                            child: Center(
                              child: new Text((index + 1).toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text("abc")),
            ],

          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Lotto(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: oh great :) Thanks. As you can see i work on a little game very interesting :) I need again add a random button for generate 5 Numbers randomly and change the color in red for the 5 Numbers selected and too i need to add a container with the number selected and a button for validate the lotto. My problem is i can't add Something Under the 49 circles, it is strange

Comment: Glad to hep. please mark this as answer if it helps you.

Comment: Need to reproduce "can't add Something Under the 49 circles", please post your code to a new question, thanks.

Comment: the code is the same. I Don't understand how to add Something Under the gridview, it seems impossible. It générates errors each times

Comment: I have update full code. You can use Column and Expaned.

Comment: i have updated the post with the complete and new code. I need to resolve the 5 Numbers selected (in red) in the zone bordered in light blue with the 5 Numbers in it just at the top of the 2 buttons. Numbers are good but design is poor, circles are too big and i am not sure i need use gridview again. The 5 circles in red in the blue light rectangular zone are generate by the function getWidget(). Thanks for your help

Comment: please do not edit original question. please post new issue to a new question. so more people can help you. thanks